# Convertir un array a objeto

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

Buenas una pregunta quiero convertir un Array de pares a un objeto es decir este ejemplo le presento, me siento atascado en esta parte he intentado con un for pero lo que consigo es que el key es numerico y no como les estoy presentando :(

```
let user = [
  ['evento', 'ejemplo'],
  ['token', '09XsasqweqweZasd91']
]
let object = {
    evento: 'ejemplo',
    token: '09XsasqweqweZasd91'
}
```

Comment: ¿Te refieres  a ponerlo así: `{evento: 'ejemplo'}, {token: '09XsasqweqweZasd91'}`?

Comment: e.e preferible colocarlo en un solo objeto y no separado.

Comment: Esos son los únicos datos o puede haber más

Comment: La pregunta no es clara, pulsa en [edit] para completarla. ¿Quieres crear el objeto partiendo de `user` o quieres crear el objeto directamente, a mano? ¿Cómo debe quedar el objeto? ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores tienes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

se puede hacer con el for como queres , te dejo una alternativa ademas con el reduce que toma el array y lo reduce a un unico valor , te dejo para que leas mas sobre este metodo
[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce)

```js
let user = [
  ['evento', 'ejemplo'],
  ['token', '09XsasqweqweZasd91']
]


const obj = user.reduce((acumulador,elemento)=>{
    acumulador[elemento[0]]=elemento[1]
    return acumulador

},{})

console.log(obj);
```

para el for tenes que barrer cada posicion del array y fijar la primera posición en la clave y la segunda en el valor

```js
let user = [
  ['evento', 'ejemplo'],
  ['token', '09XsasqweqweZasd91']
]

const obj = {}
  for(let i= 0; i<user.length ;i++){
    obj[user[i][0]]=user[i][1]
}
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Para agregar propiedades a un objeto puedes hacerlo así:

```
objeto['nombrePropiedad'] = 'valor';
```

```js
let user = [
  ['evento', 'ejemplo'],
  ['token', '09XsasqweqweZasd91']
]

// objeto vacío
let object = {};

user.forEach(par => {
    // recorrer los pares del arreglo
    // agregar la propidad con el nombre en la posicion 0
    // y el valor en la posicion 1
    object[par[0]] = par[1];

});



console.log(object);
```

Comment: no hay una forma de hacerlo con un for ? o un Object.assign o map ?

Comment: Se puede de varias formas. Qué tiene de malo el forEach ?

Comment: @Aisakk Con Object.assign() no se podría, esta es una forma que puedes usar.